# Server Response Issue

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, server

I am using Amazon Instance for hosting Website . My Amazon has c4.4xlarge installed as a Instance Type . Where as I am using Ubuntu ( not ubuntu server ) as the Operation System . I am also using RDS for the database so the only load the system has is of Apache .

My Server load goes to maximum 50% and database connection goes to 500-600 . At that time the server response time become too much slow . At the current time i have Server load of 2% and db connection around 8-10 and ajax call take 1.2 Seconds to retrieve data where as same ajax call take around 8-15 seconds when i have the maximum usage of server .

I want the website to be fast . Where as on the website i have 5 iframes so its like when we have 500 active users they would be having 5 more website inside the panel of that webpage .Every website in iframe also send the request to there own server after 1-5 seconds continuously . At that time the performance goes bad and sometime even the Firefox hangs .

I did some changes in the apache config file by changing the memory location and db connection but that didnt help . Is there any other way to imporve the performance of the website .

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not that sure about the detail about your server, but I think it will be strange that you have 500-600 connections to your database. Just ask for sure: are you connecting your database directly from client??? If no, check you server side code, make sure that you are not creating lots of connection pool, your server db driver should have only one connection pool and reuse the connections.

Another thing is, pls check the size of your database, and make sure you have created all necessary indexes. If you have a query that won't fix any indexes of that table, database will have to scan all data so your response will be slow.

Comment: We have 2 things running one is the software which is made using Codeignitor framework and the website made of wordpress . Apart from that there is no way that user can access the database . Where as the database libraray is added in the autoload libraray of codeignitor . The database size is hardly 4 MB . But the server response get slow only when we have lots of db connections where as the RDS server use less than 50% usage

Comment: I don't sure if 4MB dataset will get bad performance or not, but I think I won't be 1s or 2 s. I think you are connecting to database by Codeignitor on server side, so you may need to do php profiling to see why you are having that many connections. It's not normal. You can use a jmete or other testing tool to make stress on your server locally, and then check the profiler to see why do you have that many db connections. Even if it's the autoload library of codieignitor, I think there is still a chance that you make some mistake with it. take a deep look into it.

Comment: I have added the screenshot of DB Connections . The performance may get bad because of 5 iframes in the page and load comes on the apache server . As 500 -600 Db Connection could represent the number of user and if every user is accessing the 5 different webstie throug iframe on the same page and every 5 iframe website sending request after every 1-5 seconds that could effect the performance . I can see code again but there is no way that there is another way of connection apart from Wordpress and Codeignitor

Comment: I just checked mysql documents that a connection pool can have 100 connections by default, so I guess you open 5 connection pool for each iframes(actually I am not so familiar with php, so just guess) , I think there is an option in your framework to set up the connection pool size, limit it to a smaller size if you don't need that much connections.

Comment: The iframes are opening different website which are on different domain and server .

Comment: Ah, ok, that make sense , you can try to limit the connection number of the pool, if it is still enough for you server